# Change the iOS lock screen audio poster when playing from web

Tags: ios, html, audio, jplayer, lockscreen

I am building a website that plays an icecast mp3 stream using jPlayer and I'd want it to display the poster when listening the stream and the phone is locked.

jPlayer generates the following code which I guess it's the code that iOS uses for playing the audio, correct me if I am wrong.

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_1" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/logo.jpg" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: inline;">
    <audio id="jp_audio_1" preload="none" src="http://example.com:8000/stream_64.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS only supports the poster art for video tags: [Audio and Video HTML](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW1)